# Sum an Alias Column that already has a calculation in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the % Margin of an Alias column and its bugging me I'm not getting it right, and it is probably so simple.

My query below is what I am using and I have created the column Profit by subtracting `OH.TotalSellPrice` from `OH.TotalCostPrice` columns.  I need to get the % margin, So I will need to `SUM` the newly created column, divide that by the `OH.TotalSellPrice` column and then `* 100` to get the margin.

```
    SELECT U.Name AS [Created By], 
    SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice) as [Sale value],
    SUM (OH.TotalSellPrice-OH.TotalCostPrice) as [Profit], 
    COUNT(OH.OrderID) / 100 AS ID1
    FROM OrderHeader AS OH WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN Users AS U WITH(NOLOCK) ON U.UserID = OH.CreatedByID
    WHERE OH.Deleted = 0 AND OH.OrderType = 1 
and U.UserID in (129,245,336,337,378,387,388,425,427,433,458,480, 489, 370,458)
    and OH.Invoiced=1
    GROUP BY U.Name
```

Comment: Can you give the input data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the calculation on the aggregated values rather than the alias column names, like so:

```
(SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice-OH.TotalCostPrice) / 
 SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice))*100 AS PercentageMargin
```

So full query would look like this:

```
SELECT U.Name AS [Created By], 
    SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice) as [Sale value],
    SUM (OH.TotalSellPrice-OH.TotalCostPrice) as [Profit], 
    COUNT(OH.OrderID) / 100 AS ID1,
    (SUM (OH.TotalSellPrice-OH.TotalCostPrice) / 
     SUM(OH.TotalSellPrice))*100 AS PercentageMargin
FROM OrderHeader AS OH WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN Users AS U WITH(NOLOCK) ON U.UserID = OH.CreatedByID
    WHERE OH.Deleted = 0 AND OH.OrderType = 1 
and U.UserID in (129,245,336,337,378,387,388,425,427,433,458,480, 489, 370,458)
    and OH.Invoiced=1
    GROUP BY U.Name
```

Comment: @user1731335 no problem, feel free to use the up vote arrow on the answer (in addition to the checkmark) if you want to share the love.